# Bootstrap Carousel width and picture issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Been working with bootstrap for the first time and I've run into an issue with my carousel.

When I create a carousel it instantly fills the entire width of the screen. In my case I only want my carousel to span from the far left home button to the first right login button.

Also, is it possible to have a carousel that adjust to my pictures? Their all the same dimensions, but for whatever reason my carousel seems to zoom on the pictures.

I'm hoping someone with a bit more experience can direct me towards the appropriate changes, or give more information about carousels. Thank You

Demo: [my WIP emulation demo](http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/lab4/jraudi)

css:

```
   /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Carousel:

```
          <!-- Carousel            
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->                 
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>   
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="images/service.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">         
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Place Holder</h1>
          <p>Place Holder</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="images/classic.png" alt="Second slide"> 
      <div class="container">            
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Place Holder</h1>
          <p>Place Holder</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>               
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="images/new2016.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">           
        <div class="carousel-caption">                
          <h1>PH</h1>
          <p>PH</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="images/a6lease.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>PH</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          <p>PH</p>
        </div>               
      </div>              
    </div>
  </div>                
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">                                                                                                                                                  
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>               
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-s$
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></sp$
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>    
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: Just add `container` class to your `myCarousel` like `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">`

Comment: The code for your "chevron-right" is broken there by the way. your `a` and `span` tags are not closed properly and something towards the ends of those lines is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the grid system for that. Put your carousel inside a `row` and then inside a column spanning the width you need, e.g. `col-lg-10` and add the button you are mentioning in another column `cl-lg-2`.

I prepared a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/8rd9tfwf/1/

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->                 
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>   
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="images/service.png" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">         
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Place Holder</h1>
              <p>Place Holder</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="images/classic.png" alt="Second slide"> 
          <div class="container">            
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Place Holder</h1>
              <p>Place Holder</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>               
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="images/new2016.png" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">           
            <div class="carousel-caption">                
              <h1>PH</h1>
              <p>PH</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="images/a6lease.png" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>PH</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
              <p>PH</p>
            </div>               
          </div>              
        </div>
      </div>                
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">                                                                                                                                                  
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>               
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-s$
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></sp$
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>    
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-8 col-sm-2"></div>
```

EDIT: Updated jsFiddle. I had copied your broken HTML before, now it's fixed.

Comment: LOL yeah sorry about that broken code part, it was going on 2 AM and I was struggling to figure out the problem. Anyway your suggestion helped, I ultimately had to change the span to an 8 and realign everything.